# Error in ASP.NET Core : no service for type [...] has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I get this error

> No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' has been registered

when I tried to create user and role in the startup file, can you please help me solve this issue. The error is happening on the line

```
var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
```

Here's my full code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<LoginDbContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoginConnection")));
        //ajouter le service d'authentification Identity
        services.AddIdentity<LoginUser, LoginRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 2;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;

        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<LoginDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Login/Login";
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Login/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login/AccessDenied";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);

        });
        //ajouter le service MVC
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseAuthentication();  // ajouter le module d'authentification au middleware mvc

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        CreateRoles(serviceProvider);
    }

    private void CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {

        var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<LoginUser>>();
        Task<IdentityResult> roleResult;
        string email = "someone@somewhere.com";

        //Check that there is an Administrator role and create if not
        Task<bool> hasAdminRole = roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Administrator");
        hasAdminRole.Wait();

        if (!hasAdminRole.Result)
        {
            roleResult = roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Administrator"));
            roleResult.Wait();
        }

        //Check if the admin user exists and create it if not
        //Add to the Administrator role

        Task<LoginUser> testUser = userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        testUser.Wait();

        if (testUser.Result == null)
        {
            LoginUser administrator = new LoginUser();
            administrator.Email = email;
            administrator.UserName = email;

            Task<IdentityResult> newUser = userManager.CreateAsync(administrator, "_AStrongP@ssword!");
            newUser.Wait();

            if (newUser.Result.Succeeded)
            {
                Task<IdentityResult> newUserRole = userManager.AddToRoleAsync(administrator, "Administrator");
                newUserRole.Wait();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[Error pîcture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Hp2.png)

Answer (score 0):

> `var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();`

The `RoleManager` type is `IdentityRole`, while you register it as `LoginRole`. Change it to this:

```
services.AddIdentity<LoginUser, IdentityRole>
```

In addition, the `Authentication` middleware should be before the `Authorization` middleware.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```